# VBA, Saves Excel doc from range but adds extra spaces

Tags: vba, excel, macros

So I have a file that runs a bunch of macros that are a little complicated and I want the first step to be to save the file under a different name so that the file with the macros can be reused. The problem I am having is that it saves the name of the file to the value in the cell, but it adds a space before and after the name of the file. Can I fix that?

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()

'Pick range where file name is stored
Saveasname = Range("L2").Value

'Save the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\MyFilePath\ " & Saveasname & " .xlsm"

End Sub
```

I should also mention that I have tried deleting extra spaces around the saveasname, but they either come back automatically or the macro won't run. :/ 
Any suggestions would be helpful.

---

UPDATE: Thanks for your answers! I found out how I messed it up. I added another field to the name I wanted for the file and it had illegal characters in it (a colon), so I fixed that and now everything is working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try just changing `saveasname` to `& trim(saveasname) &`.  Or, trim the declaration part `Saveasname = Trim(Range("L2").Value)`

Comment: So, I'm having another problem now. It isn't working at all now, even though I had gotten it to work before.

Comment: What do you mean by `isn't working at all now`?  Does it error out as soon as you call `SaveWorkbook`?  Or it crashes on the first line?  Or on the second line?  Does it give any error message at all?  Does it work when `L2` contains some values but not others?

Comment: So, I just updated my question to explain. The error message occurs at the line that starts 

    ActiveWorkbooks.SaveAs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing this spaces from `FileName` String should work ;)

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()

'Pick range where file name is stored
Saveasname = Range("L2").Value

'Save the workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\MyFilePath\" & Saveasname & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I tried marking your answer as accepted but when I do a message pops up that says an error occurred. :\

Answer (score 2):

"removing the spaces around the saveasname" should not mean changing this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\MyFilePath\ " & Saveasname & " .xlsm"
```

to this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\MyFilePath\ " &Saveasname& " .xlsm"
```

It should mean changing it to this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\MyFilePath\" & Saveasname & ".xlsm"
```

which would then work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you! This is the same thing suggested by Limak, but yours spelled it out more clearly and really helped. Thanks!